# mongoid/mongodb and rake task authorization in production/passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mongoid

When trying to run `rake db:seed` on my app, I get the error:

> Database command 'count' failed: {"assertion"=>"unauthorized db:app_development lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1", "assertionCode"=>10057, "errmsg"=>"db assertion failure", "ok"=>0.0}

I get the same error with `db:drop`

Mmy app is connecting to the DB fine, it's just these rake taks are failing, and I'm not sure wh.  I dont think seeding should need admin privileges.  Maybe it's a passenger issue?

Comment: Does your mongoDB require username and password when connecting? Also: are you using mongoid or mongomapper (or other)?

Comment: i am using mongoid, and yes i have a user setup for my database. the app is accessing the database fine with those credentials, but do the mongoid rake tasks need admin access?  and if so, how can i grant that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the username and password set in mongoid.yml for rake tasks to be able to connect to your database.

Example:

```
production:
  host: host-name
  port: 27017
  username: itsmeyo
  password: supasecret
  database: project_production
```

You can also have them set in environment variables, but they need to be set.

```
password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
```